# Got "failed to sufficiently increase receive buffer size" error for cloudflared

Tags: kubernetes, udp, cloudflare, rancher, rancher-desktop

I have a local Kubernetes created by Rancher Desktop. I have deployed a named Cloudflared Tunnel based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/cloudflare/argo-tunnel-examples/tree/86a2dccc880669ef3b5f9f2e6c2f034242c08f12/named-tunnel-k8s).

I recently started to get error:

> failed to sufficiently increase receive buffer size (was: 208 kiB, wanted: 2048 kiB, got: 416 kiB). See https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Receive-Buffer-Size for details.

Note this does not affect the actual function of Cloudflared Tunnel, which is more like a warning. However, I do hope to fix it.

I have read the content in the link. However, this is running in a pod, so I am not sure how to fix it.

Below is full log:

```bash
2023-03-18 00:27:51.450Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Starting tunnel tunnelID=c9aa4140-fee8-4862-a479-3c1faacbd816
2023-03-18 00:27:51.450Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Version 2023.3.1
2023-03-18 00:27:51.450Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.19.7, GoArch: arm64
2023-03-18 00:27:51.451Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Settings: map[config:/etc/cloudflared/config/config.yaml cred-file:/etc/cloudflared/creds/credentials.json credentials-file:/etc/cloudflared/creds/credentials.json metrics:0.0.0.0:2000 no-autoupdate:true]
2023-03-18 00:27:51.453Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Generated Connector ID: a2d07b8a-3343-4b28-bbb5-a0cc951d5093
2023-03-18 00:27:51.453Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Initial protocol quic
2023-03-18 00:27:51.456Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF ICMP proxy will use 10.42.0.32 as source for IPv4
2023-03-18 00:27:51.456Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF ICMP proxy will use fe80::3c91:31ff:fe74:68ee in zone eth0 as source for IPv6
2023-03-18 00:27:51.456Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z WRN The user running cloudflared process has a GID (group ID) that is not within ping_group_range. You might need to add that user to a group within that range, or instead update the range to encompass a group the user is already in by modifying /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range. Otherwise cloudflared will not be able to ping this network error="Group ID 65532 is not between ping group 1 to 0"
2023-03-18 00:27:51.456Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z WRN ICMP proxy feature is disabled error="cannot create ICMPv4 proxy: Group ID 65532 is not between ping group 1 to 0 nor ICMPv6 proxy: socket: permission denied"
2023-03-18 00:27:51.460Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Starting Hello World server at 127.0.0.1:34545
2023-03-18 00:27:51.460Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Starting metrics server on [::]:2000/metrics
2023-03-18 00:27:51.462Z 2023/03/18 00:27:51 failed to sufficiently increase receive buffer size (was: 208 kiB, wanted: 2048 kiB, got: 416 kiB). See https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Receive-Buffer-Size for details.
2023-03-18 00:27:51.592Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Connection ca329025-1f06-4f36-a8b2-27eda979345d registered with protocol: quic connIndex=0 ip=198.41.192.107 location=LAX
2023-03-18 00:27:51.760Z 2023-03-18T00:27:51Z INF Connection a25fdab3-adff-4be5-8eb3-c22d593dfbc5 registered with protocol: quic connIndex=1 ip=198.41.200.193 location=SJC
2023-03-18 00:27:52.670Z 2023-03-18T00:27:52Z INF Connection ef583d03-d123-4e8e-b8ad-37eed817d2da registered with protocol: quic connIndex=2 ip=198.41.200.113 location=SJC
2023-03-18 00:27:53.684Z 2023-03-18T00:27:53Z INF Connection 25609514-8c37-451e-b4ac-1fb9fba2b9b8 registered with protocol: quic connIndex=3 ip=198.41.192.37 location=LAX
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My `cloudflared` pod is running under `hm-cloudflared` namesapce.

So I can get the node name by:

```bash
kubectl get pods -o wide -n hm-cloudflared

NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE   IP           NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cloudflared-7cdf78df46-x5fb7   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13 (93s ago)   26m   10.42.0.82   lima-rancher-desktop   <none>           <none>
```

Once getting the node name that the pod is running in, then you can ssh into the Kubernetes node by [kubectl-plugins](https://github.com/luksa/kubectl-plugins):

```bash
# Install kubectl-plugins
git clone https://github.com/luksa/kubectl-plugins $HOME/kubectl-plugins
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/kubectl-plugins

# SSH into the Kubernetes node by kubectl-plugins
kubectl ssh node lima-rancher-desktop
```

Inside the Kubernetes node, based on https://github.com/quic-go/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Receive-Buffer-Size#non-bsd,
I can increase the UDP receive buffer size by:

```bash
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2500000
```

This command would increase the maximum receive buffer size to roughly 2.5 MB.

Now just restart the `cloudflared` pod, the the issue should be gone! Hopefully it helps save some people time in future!